# GXT - Using TextMetrics server side

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I need to get an exact amount of lines in TextArea on server side from large string. I've passed textArea width and nrOfLines to server side and here I need to return amount of text that will fit exactly in Text Area from client. I tried to use TextMetrics on server side but It's not possible while I dont have the element. Also tried to send element to server but it's not Serializable. So is there a way to know the text width on server side?

Answer (score 2):

The TextMetrics class doesn't actually measure the text itself, but instead delegates to the browser where the code is running, so that all the styles can be properly applied.

This means that you cannot run any TextMetrics methods anywhere except inside a browser - and you probably don't want to run a browser on the server. Of course, you could run a browser on the server, but even that might not be sufficient - the user might use the browser's zoom functionality, might have their OS in a mode for help with making text large for readability, or might have different fonts installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is calculate the width of the widest character ("W") and calculate how many of those characters will fit on a line and pass that number to the server.  The client is the only one that knows which font it is using and each client could be using a different font since GXT themes usually only specify a font family and exact fonts may vary between systems.